# 英語が残っている: アカウント復元ページの説明: Forgot your account's password?

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

行き方

1. お問い合わせページでパスワードを復元を選択
2. 出現するポップアップにあるリンクをクリック

[image: forgot]

Answer (score 1):

> Forgot your account's password? Enter your email address and we'll send you a recovery link.

パスワードをお忘れですか？メールアドレスを入力していただければ再設定用のリンクをお送りします。